# How can I fasten a replace function?

Tags: excel, vba

to update the data in a weekly database I refresh the links to the linked external excel workbooks with a replace function. The search and replace value of the function is a string (e.g. 08-21 for august 2021) which I manually type in cells of the database.

As a result the macro changes the cells from e.g =HLOOKUP($F$2;P:...\08-21.xls]sheet1'!$B$1:$AH$221;45;FALSE) to =HLOOKUP($F$2;P:...\09-21.xls]sheet1'!$B$1:$AH$221;45;FALSE)

My issue is that the code is running to slow (more than a minute) and I have to refresh all 7 days of a week because I created for each day a macro (the reason for this is that some weeks belongs to 2 months --> I didn't find another solution for this)

This is how my code looks right now:

```
With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

  
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database1")
    range("C4:C67").Replace Cells(9, 13), Cells(10, 13)
       
    End With

    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("database2")
        range("B5:B194").Replace Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1)

    End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dashboard").Activate
End With
```

Comment: Try [ChangeLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink) method?

Comment: Try commenting the line `.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. If the code becomes faster, this only means that your workbook is full of formulas and the big time is the result of calculations. Theoretically, `Replace` should be very fast on such small ranges...

Comment: As far as I know ChangeLink is only applicable on a complete Worksheet and I have to update a specific range. This is grounded in the issue that a week could be located in two months

Comment: @FaneDuru I tried and it doesn't get faster

Comment: Your code works on the active sheet, not where you think it works. You should adapt the code to refer the necessary sheet `.range("C4:C67").Replace .Cells(9, 13), .Cells(10, 13)` and  `.range("B5:B194").Replace .Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 1)`. The necessary "." (dots) are missing...

Comment: @FaneDuru sadly it takes the same amount of time... :(

Comment: I did not suggest that it will solve the problem... I tried explaining that the code does not do what you think it does. Please, try copying one of the two sheets content in a new workbook and run the code (only) on that new sheet. Without any optimization. Does it run in the same way?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes it runs the same.

Comment: If not something confidential, can you share this testing workbook? I would like to test it on my computer, until I'll leave the office...

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's about sensitive company data.

Comment: No problem. I cannot imagine why such a long time for such small ranges, without testing. I suppose you restart your computer and tried again... :)

Comment: You have a drive letter P: is that a network drive ? If so that could explain the long time.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes it's the companys data server